# How to make entire tkinter GUI the canvas without any borders?

Tags: python, tkinter, seaborn

I'm trying to create a tkinter GUI that shows a heatmap only. However, I do want the heatmap to fill the entire GUI and not show any borders (in this case, I want the heatmap to fill in the white space of the GUI).

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import tkinter


yp = [1.52,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.1,0.4]
xp = [0.7,0.5,0.3,0.8,0.5,0.1]

#writing funtion to create heatmap
def cplot():

    xCord = np.array(xp)
    yCord = np.array(yp)

    #defining heatmap dimensions
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    #ploting heat map with x and y coordinates
    sb.kdeplot(xCord, yCord, shade = True, cmap = "Reds", alpha = 0.4)
    ax.invert_yaxis()
    plt.axis("off")
    plt.rcParams["figure.dpi"] = 500
    plt.show()

    return fig

#creating GUI
root = tkinter.Tk()

#creating grids
root.columnconfigure(0, minsize = 10)
root.rowconfigure([0, 1], minsize = 10)

# #setting title name
root.wm_title("test")

#creating label
label = tkinter.Label(root, text="Matplotlib with Seaborn in Tkinter")

#assigning variable to create chart from function above
fig = cplot()

#creating the space where chart is created in GUI
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
canvas.draw()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tkinter.TOP, fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
#canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side = "left")

tkinter.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to create your Axes differently. Instead of:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
```

Use:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
```

so that the axes occupies the whole space of the figure